# Prevent escaping of special characters in LaTeX output

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

By default the LaTeX output generated by Sphinx escapes the LaTeX markup. So if I write:

```
Normal text

.. only:: latex

   \textbf{latex only text}
```

After a `make latexpdf` call it will be

```
Normal text

textbf\{latex only text\}
```

in LaTeX. So all chars are escaped, and it is not a LaTeX code anymore. Is there a way to pass LaTeX code directly to the tex source generated by Sphinx?

MWE is to do a `sphinx-quickstart` accepting defaults, then inputing the above ReST code somewhere in `index.rst` and finally building the thing with `make latexpdf` (`make.bat latexpdf` on Windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the `raw` directive:

```
.. raw:: latex

   \textbf{latex only text}
```

If you only want this text in LaTeX output, you will need to combine it with the `only` directive.